# Как с помощью webhook получить оповещение о том, что в тикет добавлен исполнитель?

Tags: jira

Идея такова: когда в тикет добавляют исполнителя (assignee) - посылать вебхук. Такого события в настройках вебхуков я не нашел. Подозреваю, что нужно использовать JQL - но тоже не знаю как подступиться к нему.